# How do I migrate to Meteor 0.9 with own package on github

Tags: meteor, package, meteorite

I have a Meteor 0.8.3 project which I try to update with `meteor update`, but I get the result:

```
This project is at the latest release which is compatible with your
current package constraints.
```

I have established the problem is two customised 'packages' that I use from github, and which I refer to in `smart.json`:

```
{
  "packages": {
    "accounts-ui": {
        "git": "https://github.com/RacingTadpole/accounts-ui.git",
        "branch": "master"
    },
    "accounts-ui-unstyled": {
        "git": "https://github.com/RacingTadpole/accounts-ui-unstyled.git",
        "branch": "master"
    }
  }
}
```

I established this by removing all packages, then updating Meteor, then adding them back one by one. I got the error:

```
Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
Refreshing package metadata. This may take a moment.
Could not satisfy all the specified constraints:
Error: conflict: accounts-ui can't be satisfied
```

My `.meteor/packages` file looks like this:

```
standard-app-packages
less
(... lots more I'm leaving out ...)
accounts-google
accounts-ui
accounts-password
iron-router
```

I updated this last line to `iron:router` of course.

The `packages.js` file in `accounts-ui` is:

```
Package.describe({
    summary: "Simple templates to add login widgets to an app"
});
Package.on_use(function (api) {
    // Export Accounts (etc) to packages using this one.
    api.imply('accounts-base', ['client', 'server']);
    api.use('accounts-ui-unstyled', 'client');
    api.use('less', 'client');
    api.add_files(['login_buttons.less'], 'client');
});
```

The same file in the other custom package is quite long, but the link is [here](https://github.com/RacingTadpole/accounts-ui-unstyled/blob/master/package.js).

How do I migrate these two packages to Meteor 0.9.2.2? Thanks!

Comment: have you read https://hackpad.com/Migrating-Packages-zN0we9sIjkH?

Comment: by the way, why are you using a customized version?

Comment: thanks juanpastas - I never put my customized packages on Atmosphere, so I wasn't sure how to apply the info in that link to my situation - how do I?  I'm using a customised version so that I can change the appearance of the login button and dropdown form.

Comment: you should use official `accounts-ui` and `accounts-ui-unstyled`, the latter package allows to set custom style. So: I would remove custom packages from `smart.json`, and follow 0.9 upgrade process, which is self explained by `meteor update`

Comment: Great, I'll give that a go.